# eslint enforce space after the single-line-if parentheses

Tags: eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I'm quite new to ESLint and I couldn't find a rule that does what I want. Consider the following code:

```js
if(someCondition)i++;
```

I want to enforce a single space after the parentheses, so that we should have the following instead:

```js
if(someCondition) i++;
```

However I simply couldn't find such a rule; it's not `space-before-function-paren` (obviously), `keyword-spacing` (which only affects the spacing after `if`) or `space-before-blocks` (since this is a single-line-if, there's no block). Please help. Thanks!

P.S. Same rule should apply to single-line-while as well.

Comment: Sounds like a feature request. What type of answer are you looking for?

Comment: Anything that can achieve what I described, including custom rule (if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ESLint doesn't have such a rule and the [policy](https://github.com/eslint/eslint#stylistic-rule-updates) says that they will no longer consider such proposals, I ended up writing my own rules as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
    "single-line-control-statement-spacing": {
        meta: {
            type: "layout",
            docs: {
                description: "Enforces consistent spacing in single-line control statements.",
            },
            fixable: "whitespace",
        },
        create(context) {
            const sourceCode = context.getSourceCode();

            function checkSpaceAfter(node) {
                if(!node) return;
                if(node.loc.start.line !== node.loc.end.line) return; // Not single-line
                const body = node.consequent || node.body;
                const token = sourceCode.getFirstToken(body);
                const prev = sourceCode.getTokenBefore(token);
                const start = prev.range[1];
                const end = token.range[0];
                if(start === end) {
                    context.report({
                        loc: {
                            start: sourceCode.getLocFromIndex(start),
                            end: sourceCode.getLocFromIndex(end),
                        },
                        message: "There should be a single space after control statements.",
                        fix(fixer) {
                            return fixer.replaceTextRange([start, end], " ");
                        },
                    });
                }
            }

            return {
                IfStatement: checkSpaceAfter,
                DoWhileStatement: checkSpaceAfter,
                ForInStatement: checkSpaceAfter,
                ForOfStatement: checkSpaceAfter,
                ForStatement: checkSpaceAfter,
                WhileStatement: checkSpaceAfter,
            };
        },
    },
};
```

I then use [eslint-plugin-local-rules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-local-rules) to enable this rule in my project.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/eslint/eslint/discussions/15267#discussioncomment-1597748

> I think we don't have that rule in the core.
>
> `keyword-spacing` can disallow `if (foo)return;`, `space-before-blocks` can disallow `if (foo){`, but it seems that there is no rule that would disallow if `(foo)bar;` and enforce `if (foo) bar;`

Answer (score -2):

Simple, but effective:

```
$ cat input 
  if (condition)i++;
  if (condition)i--
  
  while ( this ^ foo || bar )continue
  for (true ||
         true )z--
```

Naive solution, but probably ok.

```
$ cat input | busybox sed -e 's/)\([a-zA-Z_]\)/) \1/'
if (condition) i++;
if (condition) i--

while ( this ^ foo || bar ) continue
for (true ||
       true ) z--
```

This will put a space between ) and the first letter of a variable name (a-z_).

Consider my answer here (and others') for tips on how to process all files that contain the undesired pattern:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675881/remove-trailing-spaces-from-text-files-only-when-necessary/676367#676367

Comment: This was an eslint question. How is your answer relevant to that?

Comment: see comment: "Anything that can achieve what I described,"

Comment: First of all, there're many cases where your regular expression doesn't cover. Secondly, and most importantly, I explicitly stated “eslint enforce space” in the very title of my question. So no, your answer has nothing to do with what I described.

Comment: Then we have a different definition of anything.