# What is the eslint rule to to enforce a space after the closing parentheses of a single-line if statement?

Tags: eslint

For the life of me I cannot find an ESLint rule to enforce the following:

```js
// Bad:
if (foo)bar;

// Good:
if (foo) bar;
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Note: This question appears to have also been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67496275/eslint-enforce-space-after-the-single-line-if-parentheses), but never received an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don‘t think that there is a specific build-in rule for your use case, but you could combine the **space-before-blocks** with the **block** rule if you are willing to never omit curly braces around blocks, even when they are optional.

Comment: Nah I wanted something that allows omission of curly braces. Curious that after all this time it's not part of the core rule set. Single-line if statements are very common. Pervasive, even...

Comment: As last resort, you could also create your own custom rule.

Comment: True, though I have bigger fish to fry at present...